# How to get data matching against multiple column values in same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get the ID of those books which belong to country 79 AND author 80 AND publisher 91

```
SELECT id FROM books WHERE ( 
    (filter = 'country' AND cat = 79) 
        AND
    (filter = 'author' AND cat = 80)
        AND
    (filter = 'publisher' AND cat = 91)
    )
```

Here is my table structure

```
+----+----------+-----+
| ID | FITER    | CAT |
+----+----------+-----+
|  1 | country  | 79  |
|  1 | author   | 80  |
|  1 | publisher| 91  |
|  2 | country  | 476 |
|  2 | author   | 85  |
|  2 | publisher| 121 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

Thank you

Comment: So you want to get first 3 records from this table? Or do you want to get information from some other table?

Comment: @dotnetom : I want to just get the id 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem with this kind of table structure, do you really have that many filters that they can't be columns on their own?. Anyway, it would be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id 
FROM books b
WHERE filter = 'country' AND cat = 79
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM books 
            WHERE filter = 'author' AND cat = 80
            AND id = b.id)
AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM books 
            WHERE filter = 'publisher' AND cat = 91
            AND id = b.id);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the SELECT 1 FROM...?

Comment: @Mic `EXISTS` checks whether it returns a row or not, it doesn't matter what's in the `SELECT`, so I choose `SELECT 1` to show explicitly that I don't need any columns from the inner table, just to check existence